# State.when vs Item.state property

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

The `when` property of a QML `State` type can be used to control when the state should be applied by a boolean expression.

When I set the `state` property of an QML `Item` explicitly that seems to override the `when` properties of all state objects as in the following code:

```
Item {
    id: item

    anchors.fill: parent
    states: [
        State {
            name: "when state"
            when: 1 === 1
        },
        State {
            name: "explicit state"
        }
    ]

    onStateChanged: console.log("state = " + state)

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent

        onPressed: item.state = "explicit state"
        onReleased: item.state = ""
    }
}
```

The initial state of `item` is the "when state" as it is determined by the `when` expression. When the `MouseArea` is pressed the state turns to the "explicit state". After release of the mouse button the state turns to the default state (""). It seems that the `when` state evaluation is ceased.

Is there any way to "recover" to the "when" state evaluation somehow?

Comment: Maybe something like `onReleased: item.state = item.state`?

Comment: No, that unfortunately does not change the state at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `when` properties on states are evaluated:

- When a group of states is initially created
- When a state's `when` is altered (either by being set, or when any of the properties that one of the `when` bindings rely on change)

So no, you can't really "reset" it. I'd suggest not mixing the two methods if you can avoid it.